# Checking java List<object> object type

Tags: java, list, object, casting

I have a generic function that returns a `List<?>`. If it works correctly, it will return a `List<LightSensor>`, but I cannot directly convert the result of the function to a variable of type `List<LightSensor>`. How can I check if the class in the List is a LightSensor correctly? (e.g. check if `List<?> = List<LightSensor>`)
Also, What is the best way to cast it correctly once I've checked?
BTW the class LightSensor extends Object and a version of Serializable

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your generic function.

Comment: Also, in Java, we call them "methods", not "functions".

Comment: It's nothing special, why do you need to see it? It just returns a List<?>. If you really want to see it, go here: http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/df/d9a/classorg_1_1bukkit_1_1configuration_1_1MemorySection.html#a3a5a98698602756e65b84704399e787e

Comment: Why did my question format incorrectly? Each word List was supposed to show the class type

Comment: @Pocketkid2 - read the "help".  Inlined code should be enclosed in backticks.

Comment: Because the text editor interprets "<" and ">" as html tags.  You have to use "&lt;" and "&gt;" instead.

Comment: @TJamesBoone - there's a better way!

Comment: @StephenC You're right, tunnel vision.  Backticks are preferable.

Comment: Sorry to be a newbie at Java, but I don't really what "help" section you're talking about. and what a backtick is.

Comment: @Pocketkid2 - 1) I'm refering to to help, etc links you see when you are editing a Question / Answer.  2) http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I check if the class in the List is a LightSensor correctly? (e.g. check if `List<?> = List<LightSensor>`)

AFAIK, the only way to do this is to iterate the list and use `instanceof LightSensor` or `getClass() == LightSensor.class` on each element.

> Also, What is the best way to cast it correctly once I've checked?

Just do a typecast, and suppress the "unchecked conversion" warning.

Comment: Should I use `Object` for iterating through the `List<?>`?

Comment: @Pocketkid2 - ermm ... yes.  You've got no choice really, 'cos that's what static typing says the element type of `List<?>` is.

Answer (score 1):

Well the idiom to return a generic collection from a method is something like:

```
public <T> List<T> getTheList(Class<T> cls){
  // you might need the cls in here to create the list.
  ...
}
```

Obviously the way you use the `Class<T>` to generate the list is application specific. Most of the times this makes sense in the context of some class hierarchy, in which case `T` extends some base class or interface:

```
public <T extends MyBaseClassOrInterface> List<T> getTheList(Class<T> cls){
  ...
}
```

Again, the way you create the list is completely application dependent. If you try to keep your whole application strongly typed you might be able to avoid doing some kind of black magic to figure out the type parameter of `List<?>`. It's a strong code smell if you end up with code like that (unless obviously you are dealing with some legacy code). Besides, if the list is empty you are absolutely hopeless.